# How do I understand the concept of manifolds through this example?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

To understand the concept of manifolds, let us look at some concrete functions. Let $(U, \varphi)$ be a local chart as above.

Let $u_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the usual coordinate functions, namely, $u_i(x) = x_i$.

We can then define coordinates $x$ on $U$ as follows: For all $p \in U$, we set $x_i(p) = u_i(\varphi(p))$. Then $x_i$ are obviously $C^k$-functions on $U$.

How is $x_i$ a function? Isn't it just a value?

Comment: Because you have that definition of $x_i(p)$ for all $p$ in some $U$, then you effectively have a set of functions from $U$ to $R$. In particular, those functions are $C^k$, by the chain rule theorem.